# writing dataframe to sql db using pyodbc gives error

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have a Synapse database from which i am reading some tables to create a dataframe. I am using the below to connect and read the database tables:

```
server = 'gbs-marcus-dev-dw.database.windows.net' 
database = 'romeo' 
username = 'romeouser' 
password = 'romeopass' 
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' 

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()


# select command
query = ''' SELECT * FROM dbo.Masterdata''';
df_input_orig = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)


pyodbc.drivers() 

['SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

Post creating the dataframes, i am trying to write the resultant dataframes back to the DB and i am following the below two approches both of which give different errors.

Approch 1:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://romeouser:romeopass@gbs-marcus-dev-dw.database.windows.net/romeo?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server",echo=False)
Insight_instance.to_sql(name='Insight_Instance',con=engine, index=False,  if_exists='append')
cursor.execute('commit')
```

Error for approch 1:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111214;An attempt to complete a transaction has failed. No corresponding transaction found. (111214) (SQLEndTran)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Approch 2:

```
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER=driver;SERVER=gbs-marcus-dev-dw.database.windows.net;DATABASE=romeo;UID=romeouser;PWD=romeopass")
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://romeouser:romeopass@gbs-marcus-dev-dw.database.windows.net/romeo",echo=False)
engine.connect()
Insight_instance.to_sql(name='Insight_Instance',con=engine, index=False,  if_exists='append')
```

Error from approch 2:

```
InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/rvf5)
```

I am quite new to this and have no clue where or what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Try adding an `isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT"` argument to your `create_engine` call.

Comment: thanks, i tried that now, it did not help, same error message. Is there anything else i can try?

Comment: Perhaps try using a context manager, like [this](https://pastebin.com/sVDXNdaE).

Comment: @GordThompson I don't have access to that link.It's blocked at my end.

Comment: Can you see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KuoJ.png)?